# How to unpack a uint32 array with np.unpackbits

Tags: python, numpy

I used a piece of code to create a 2D binary valued array to cover all possible scenarios of an event. For the first round, I tested it with 2 members.

Here is my code:

```
number_of_members = 2
n = number_of_members
values = np.arange(2**n, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 1)
print('$$$ ===> ', values)
bin_array = np.unpackbits(values, axis=1)[:, -n:]
print('*** ===> ', bin_array)
```

And the result is this:

```
$$$ ===>  [[0]
           [1]
           [2]
           [3]]
*** ===>  [[0 0]
           [0 1]
           [1 0]
           [1 1]]
```

As you can see, it correctly provided my 2D binary array.

The problem begins when I intended to use `number_of_members = 20`. If I assign 20 to `number_of_members` python shows this as result:

```
$$$ ===>  [[  0]
           [  1]
           [  2]
           ...
           [253]
           [254]
           [255]]
*** ===>  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
           [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
           [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
           ...
           [1 1 1 ... 1 0 1]
           [1 1 1 ... 1 1 0]
           [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]
```

The result has 8 columns, but I expected an array of 32 columns. How can I unpack a `uint32` array?

Comment: did you forget to make `dtype=np.uint32` by some chance? Could you show the full code that caused the problem? Even if it only differs from the original by a couple of characters, details are important.

Comment: So what is your actual question? You are not using np.uint32 anywhere but the title, and your result has 2^20 rows, not 8 as you claim...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes. I changed data type to uint32. then `values` changed correctly. but the problem persists. because `unpackbits` function is just for `uint8` data type and doesn't supports bigger data type.

Comment: I see. That I can help you fix. You should post what you wrote in your comment into the question. The whole question is "how do I get a 2^20 x 32 output array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted correctly, [`np.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) operates only on `uint8` arrays. The nice thing is that you can view any type as `uint8`. You can create a `uint32` [`view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) into your data like this:

```
view = values.view(np.uint8)
```

On my machine, this is little-endian, which makes trimming easier. You can force little-endian order conditionally across all systems:

```
if values.dtype.byteorder == '>' or (values.dtype.byteorder == '=' and sys.byteorder == 'big'):
    view = view[:, ::-1]
```

Now you can unpack the bits. In fact, `unpackbits` has a nice feature that I personally added, the `count` parameter. It allows you to make your output be exactly 20 bits long instead of the full 32, without subsetting. Since the output will be mixed big-endian bits and little-endian bytes, I recommend displaying the bits in little-endian order too, and flipping the entire result:

```
bin_array = np.unpackbits(view, axis=1, count=20, bitorder='little')[:, ::-1]
```

The result is a `(1<<20, 20)` array with the exact values you want.

Comment: You are the best.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment :)